# Do I still have rights over an app I gave away?

Tags: copyright

I have created an application all by myself. I have then given its source code to a different person without explicitly agreeing on any terms of licensing.

In such a case, do I still retain the rights over the app? Can I still enforce my copyright over it?

Comment: Something similar [Seafile Ltd. gave away software to Seafile GmbH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seafile#Seafile_Ltd_and_Seafile_GmbH).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What conditions did you impose when you provided the source code?

If you didn't impose any conditions then what you did is give a [gift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_(law)). Legally a gift is irrevocable. So, no, you cannot stop him using it.

Comment: I would agree that you cannot stop him using it for private use. But without a license, the other person cannot use it for any other purpose. The software is still fully copyrighted. The gift did not include the copyright. Depending on the jurisdiction, it is not even possible to transfer copyright without a signed contract.

Comment: @wimh the gift included an implied licence the limits of which are unknown but a court is likely to determine the limits permissively